# How do I create two main windows with GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glut

I am doing an excercise where I draw three boxes across three windows using GLUT. They draw individually, but in the same project, the three windows display correctly, but immediately close the program with code 1.

```
glutInitWindowPosition(x,y);
windowOne = glutCreateWindow("windowOne");

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(-400, 400, -400, 400, -500, 500);

glutInitWindowPosition(x,y);
windowTwo = glutCreateWindow("windowTwo");

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glFrustum(-60, 60, -60, 60, 60, 200);
gluLookAt(0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

With each window in a separate file loaded in by itself, they each display exactly as they are meant to. I have a feeling I should be setting the window at some point between each init, but I don't know why. I do not have a draw function in at the moment, as I wanted to confirm this happens without the drawing code.

I should also note that I have to create separate windows, exactly as I have done, so other window drawing functions are useless.

Comment: Are you calling `glutMainLoop()` at all? If not, that would explain why your program exits immediately

Comment: too clarify, if i have one window, it works perfectly. I have got all windows working in separate files, its bringing them together I'm having the trouble with.

Comment: I've also clarrified the program crashes at " WindowThree = glutCreateWindow("3D viewing system with glFrustum()"); "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer scouring through examples, so I'll post it just in case anyone else is having similar problems.

the draw function needs to be added after each window, in the style of

```
// window one

glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
WindowOne = glutCreateWindow("orthogonal projection");
glutDisplayFunc(drawWindowOne); 

// window two
glutInitWindowPosition(650, 50);
WindowThree = glutCreateWindow("3D viewing system with glFrustum()");
glutDisplayFunc(drawWindowTwo);
```

I was using a draw function that shuffles through each window and generates its specific draw after using glutSetWindow. each draw takes place after each window is initialized, and multiple glutDisplayFunc() can be called after eachother.

I originally thought I was using glutDisplayFunc to set a pointer, so that when the display routine went through for the frame, it would only generate the last display function called, as opposed to all of them.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I told you need to do: Register a display function for each window you create.

Comment: perhaps you misunderstood me. I already had each display function registered from the start. It was the exact order in which they were registered that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never do OpenGL drawing operations in the same function in which you also create GLUT windows. It doesn't work. You need to register a display callback function for each window and do all drawing there. Calling glutMainLoop is mandatory if you want to see something sensible using GLUT.

Comment: for the purpose of finding my solution, I do not have any drawing function yet, and the glutMainLoop is already included.